# Popular JSON dinâmicamente com PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

estou trabalhando com o Laravel em um projeto de um cliente aonde pretendo montar uma estrutura de árvore com os usuários cadastrados no sistema, achei um script que realiza isso, e para isso ele utiliza JSONs para obter os dados.

A estrutura que ele funciona é da seguinte maneira:

```
{
    "name": "Top Level",
    "parent": null,
    "children": [{
            "name": "Level 2: A",
            "parent": "Top Level",
            "children": [{
                    "name": "Son of A",
                    "parent": "Level 2: A"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Daughter of A",
                    "parent": "Level 2: A"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Level 2: B",
            "parent": "Top Level"
        }
    ]
}
```

Eu tentei preparar meu JSON no mesmo formato, mas não entendi a lógica que ele irá gerar de formar automática. Eu tenho um usuário em meu banco de dados que como no exemplo ele possui `"parent": null` em meu caso: `"id_user_parent":null`, e todos os demais usuários possuem parentesco com outros IDs de usuários.

Minha dúvida é, como deixar este usuário que o `"id_user_parent":null` em primeiro e os demais ele popular com seus respectivos filhos?

Minha chamada em meu controller:

```
$users = User::select('name_first', 'name_second', 'id_user_parent')->get()
```

E o JSON de resposta do meu banco é esse:

```
[
    {
        "name_first": "Tiago",
        "name_second": "Revers Paza",
        "id_user_parent": null
    }, 
    {
        "name_first": "Yuri",
        "name_second": "Luiz Hugo da Cunha",
        "id_user_parent": 1
    }, 
    {
        "name_first": "Severino",
        "name_second": "Ben\u00edcio das Neves",
        "id_user_parent": 1
    }
]
```

Ou seja, como eu formato a estrutura que vem de resposta do meu banco de dados para a estrutura esperada para gerar a árvore de usuários?

Answer (score 1):

Assim, se isso aqui carrega um usuario:

```
$users = User::select('name_first', 'name_second', 'id_user_parent')->get()
```

você precisa criar um objeto, e popular ele conforme sua estrutura.

**Por exemplo:**

```
$data['nome'] = "julio"
```

a resposta do seu controller será

```
{"nome":"julio"}
```

se você fizer isso, e mais isso:

```
$data['users'] = $users
```

a resposta final será

```
{
 "nome":"julio",
 "users":[
    {
      "name_first": "Tiago",
      "name_second": "Revers Paza",
      "id_user_parent": null
    }, 
    {
      "name_first": "Yuri",
      "name_second": "Luiz Hugo da Cunha",
      "id_user_parent": 1
    }, 
    {
      "name_first": "Severino",
      "name_second": "Ben\u00edcio das Neves",
      "id_user_parent": 1
    }
 ]
}
```

e assim vai, até você montar a estrutura que você quer

**Para carregar os dados?**
Você pode usar as querys disponiveis no eloquent do laravel, ou criar querys para montar seu objeto completo.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é o jeito mais correto mas segui a sua ideia e montei a seguinte estrutura:

```
$users = User::select('name_first', 'name_second', 'id_user_parent')->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    if ($user['id_user_parent'] == null) {
        $main['name'] = $user['name_first'] . ' ' . $user['name_second'];
        $main['parent'] = $user['id_user_parent'];

        $data = $main;
    }
}
foreach($users as $key => $user) {
    if ($user['id_user_parent'] != null) {
        $data['children'][$key]['name'] = $user['name_first'] . ' ' . $user['name_second'];
        $data['children'][$key]['parent'] = $user['id_user_parent'];
    }
}
dd($data);

return response()->json($data);
```

E meu retorno no momento é o seguinte:

```
array:3 [▼
    "name" => "Tiago Revers Paza"
    "parent" => null
    "children" => array:2 [▼
        1 => array:2 [▼
            "name" => "Yuri Luiz Hugo da Cunha"
            "parent" => 1
        ]
        2 => array:2 [▼
            "name" => "Severino Benício das Neves"
            "parent" => 1
        ]
    ]
]
```

Ou seja, extamente como o esperando, o problema é que ele está pegando a posição 1 quando ele entra no `foreach` para verificar se ele é um nodo filho. E eu tenho que começar com a posição 0. Como faço para alterar as posições?